What does it mean for a linear map to have a "basis"?
In a lot of sources you will see statements like "the linear map $A$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors" etc. According to Wikipedia, basis is defined as follows:
A basis $B$ of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$ that spans $V$.
And, a linear map is a function between two vector spaces that preserves the operations of addition and scalar multiplication.
So, what does it mean for a linear map to have a basis? A basis is defined for a vector space, and not for a function between vector spaces. Or is there another definition for a basis of a linear map that I am not aware of?

Could you give an example of a source that uses this terminology?

"the linear map $A$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors": This means there is an orthonormal  basis $(x_i)$ for the space $V$ in which each element $x_i$ is an eigen vector of $A$.

@geetha290krm Thank you! This is what I was looking for :)

You should seek a simple example in $V:=\mathbb R^2$($F=\mathbb R$), that you could represent step by step by a drawing. I think if you can't do it, it would be interesting to suggest one, or a link to another post where it is done. These are in reality very easy things

In your case, it is more customary to say that “$A$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis”.

@geetha290krm This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

"the linear map $A$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors" means there is an orthonormal basis $(x_i)$ of $V$ such that each $x_i$ is an eigen vector of $A$.
